# How can I store values in MultiStepForm using react-hook-form and useContext?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, forms

I have tried to find a similar case on SO before, but it doesn't seem to exist here. I would like to make MultiStep Form using react-hook-form and context. In context I store my values from inputs. I have no idea what I make wrong, but finally my store doesn't contain the data. When I clicked SUBMIT button I can see the values are updated but invalid.

This is my [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-night-j9imt?file=/src/App.tsx) with current code.

UI doesn't look nice now, but the behaviour of form is what I expect actually.

Please about any help and explanation!

Comment: Does this is what you want? https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-brook-zhz15

Comment: @ManirajMurugan yes, it's exactly what I expected. Thank u. I've imagined the solution in different way, that's why I couldn't handle it.

Comment: No issues.. You need to handle the change in input box then you can store the values to respective state and hence moving the condition inside submit to ```ionInputChange``` handler function would solve your issue.